# Pycharm python interpreter incorrectly showing errors

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm importing a .py file into another `from snow_get import *`. Pycharm gives me a unresolved reference error, but when I actually run it works just fine. I get this error both with and without a **init**.py in my folder.

I did notice that the Python version is 3.7 (~/anaconda3/bin/python) whereas the project interpreter is 3.6 (also ~/anaconda3/bin/python). But I wasn't able to fix this.

[image: Undeservedly unresolved]

snow_get.py

```
import pysnow
from pprint import pprint

def foo():
    print('bar')
```

snow_post.py

```
from snow_get import *

foo()
```

prints the following:

```
/Users/hermanvanderveer/anaconda3/bin/python "/Users/hermanvanderveer/Code/RPA/Python/Coca cola/snow_post.py"
bar

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So it works just fine. But why then is Pycharm giving me the unresolved reference error?

Comment: I managed to find an explanation about relative and absolute imports here. https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works because the script is executed as in a console:

python -m script.py.

PyCharm though has 'smart' detection of errors according to standards. The import  should be done as a relative import with the '.' notation because it's your script.

Also, you can change all these errors markings in the Settings -> Editor -> Inspections

Update:

my hack is this:

```
try:
    from .data_processing import DataProcessor
except ImportError as e:
    from data_processing import DataProcessor
```

I put both versions to have the code running and to have the library loaded. This is only for the local modules and packages.

Comment: Wow, `from .snow_get import *` solved it! Thanks! Strange though, that this wasn't mentioned in any of the import explanations I found.

Comment: Wait, now it doesn't show any errors, but if I try to run it, it doesn't work...
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.snow_get'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: Exactly. That's why you need to not use the relative imports. But PyCharm will show it as an error, still it will run. Just ignore the red underlining. Learn to live with it :-D. I've updated the answer with my solution

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice workaround! It ís quite ugly, but at least my IDE is helping me again.